# Java Build Path & Maven Dependency Error - Corrupted mdm-admin-5.5.64.jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

Need help on how to resolve this error:

[image: Need help on how to resolve this error.]

JAR file is on the correct path but it seems to be corrupted and cannot be read.

I've already tried force updating the Maven Project to get the updated *jar* file but always fails and gives me a jar file with `.lastUpdated` extension. I also tried to do a Maven Clean Install and Project clean but it didn't resolve the issue as well.

Is there any other way to fix this corrupted jar file or retrieve an updated version of it?

Comment: why dont try simply deleting "mdm-admin-xxx" directory in .m2 and try again mvn clean install

Comment: @kuhajeyan also tried that. The new created jar file was corrupted as well.